# Can I mockito verify if I have a method that I test, what calls another method in the same class what calls another's class method?

Tags: java, mockito

So I have a method (`foo()`) in class `TestingThis`

```
public class TestingThis {
    // injected another class
    private HelperClass helperClass;

    public void foo() {
        bar();
    }

    public void bar() {
        helperClass.call();
    }
}
```

The test:

```
@Mock
private HelperClass helperClass;

@InjectMocks
private TestingClass testingClass;

@Test
public void fooTest() {
   testingClass.foo();

   // can I have something like this?
   verify(helperClass).call();
   verifyNoMoreInteractions(helperClass);
}
```

Can/Should I verify if a mock is called somewhere in the chain?

At the moment it says "Wanted but not invoked", what does not feel right...

Answer (score 0):

"Can/Should I verify if a mock is called somewhere in the chain?"
I dont think so. At least not in the way your doing. Since you're unit testing the foo() method, you only want to test the logic of this method, you don't care about whats inside of bar(), you will mock bar() and make it return (in case its not void) whatever you want/need. So, you don't need to check what is inside of bar() and how its behaving.

```
@Mock
private HelperClass helperClass;

@InjectMocks
private TestingClass testingClass;

@Test
public void fooTest() {
   testingClass.foo();

   // wont return anything in case the method is void ofc
   when(helperClass.bar().thenReturn(something);

   // you could verify that the mocked method got called if you need to
   verify(helperClass).bar();
}
```

If you want to post your real code maybe i can help in a better way, since an "abstract" example may not be the best way to explain.